# Find the necessary and sufficient condition on $g$ for which $f$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose two functions $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(x) = xg(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the necessary and sufficient condition on $g$ for which $f$ is differentiable at $0$. In such case find $f'(0)$.

We have $f'(0) = xg'(0) +g(0)$ and thus $f'(0) = g(0)$ if $g'(0)$ exists. So in order for $f'(0)$ to exist $g$ must be differentiable at $0$?

Comment: How do you know that $g'$ exists?

Comment: Well, the fact that $g(0)$ exists is a hypothesis of the problem: "Suppose two functions $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$..."

Comment: @user19405892 $g$ needn't be differentiable at $0$. For instance, $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}&\text{if }x\notin\Bbb Q\\ 0&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{xg(x)}{x} = g(x).
$$
So what do we have to impose on $g$ such that the limit as $x\to 0$ exists?

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition we have  $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{hg(h)-0\cdot g(0)}h =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}g(h)$ so f'(0) exists iff g is continuous at 0.